# Экранная клавиатура на Android перекрывает поля ввода формы

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, bootstrap, input

Заметил на Android 4.2.2 (Chrome 50). Есть простое модальное окно, с простой формой и несколькими полями input. стили все дефолтные.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                      <p>Simple form</p>
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input1"><span">Old pass</span></label>
                            <input type="password" id="input1" maxlength="20">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input2"><span>New pass</span></label>
                            <input type="password" id="input2" maxlength="20">
                        </div>
                        <button type="button">change pass</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

когда input в фокусе, открывается клавиатура и заслоняет поля ввода. Приходится скролить форму, чтобы видеть что вводится. Попробовал исправить с помощью

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
    $('.modal').animate({
        scrollTop: $('label').offset().top
    }, 1000);
})
```

стало лучше, но не всегда корретно скроллится. в некоторых случаях, если элементов input несколько, при выборе второго или третьего элемента скроллится в обратную сторону. как можно исправить ?

Comment: У меня точно такая же ситуация. Получилось ли у тебя найти решение?